# Skip to Content using created elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working within an in house platform, so the only way I can create elements for skip navigation is by using jQuery. I have no trouble creating the link as well as the target div (just after the header). I've add JS to get around the event delegation issue with the created link, but while the click event is firing (tested with a log) it still doesn't skip down to the newly created element #skipTarget. Also our sites use a base url, which is why the link is just '#skipTarget'. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my snippet of my JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const skipNav = $('<a id="skip-nav" alt="Skip to Content">');
  const skipSearch = $('<a id="skip-search" alt="Skip to Inventory">');
  let contentLink = window.location.pathname;
  if (contentLink == '/') {
    contentLink = '';
  }
  const skipTarget = $('<div id="#skipTarget" tabindex="-1">');
  $('body > header').after(skipTarget);
  skipNav.text('Skip to Main Content');
  skipNav.attr('href', contentLink + '#skipTarget');
  $('body > header').prepend(skipNav);
  skipSearch.text('Skip to Inventory');
  skipSearch.attr('href', contentLink + '#inventory-listing');
  $('aside#refine-search').prepend(skipSearch);

  $('header').on('click', '#skip-nav', function(event) {
    console.log('test:', event);
    console.log('contentLink: ', contentLink);
  });
});
```

```css
#skip-nav,
#skip-search {
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute;
  color: transparent;
  padding: 3px;
}

#skip-nav:active,
#skip-nav:focus,
#skip-search:active,
#skip-search:focus {
  z-index: 999;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

<header>
  <a id="skip-nav" href="#skipTarget">Skip to Main Content</a>
  
  <div>header content and menus to skip</div>
  
</header>

<div id="#skipTarget" tabindex="-1"></div>

</body>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: shouldn't it be `$('.header').on`?

Comment: There's no need to concatenate `contentLink + '#skipTarget'`. You can just use `href="#skipTarget"`

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header

Comment: @Barmar You're right about that I didn't notice the `body > header`

Comment: I turned your code into a Stack Snippet. Can you add the HTML?

Comment: I can't add the html, as it's part of our system and actually changes based on the site. The only consistent is the header within the body, followed by ever changing divs containing widgets. The content link is in place so that it works on interior pages as well as the home page.

Comment: I feel like the issue is around trying to point the href to the newly created 'skipTarget' div.

Comment: You don't have to put proprietary information, just the general structure with lorum ipsum content.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I missed it, but it was just a typo. When defining skipTarget, I set it to id=#skipTarget, rather than id=skipTarget. Thanks all for looking at it.